# kickstart %include can't open file

Tags: centos7, kickstart, rhel7, anaconda

I want to break out my kickstart user definitions into a separate file.

Trying to pull that file in with `%include`, I get an error that breaks the install:

> Unable to open input kickstart file: curl#37 - "Couldn't open file
>   /whatever/path/itry/user_section-ks.cfg"

This [doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-syntax.html#sect-kickstart-commands) 
and this [doc](http://pykickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kickstart-docs.html#include)
both say I can use it like this: `%include /path/to/file`

RH gives this example:

```
/usr/share/anaconda/user_section-ks.cfg
```

I've seen google results here and there, people using `/tmp` and `file:///`
I tried 'em both.

I've checked every name, checked permissions and se contexts run `ksvalidator` and ... I'm stumped! Don't know what I don't know :(

Comment: What section of the kickstart file? E.g., `%pre` isn't chrooted whereas `%post` is.

Comment: Refreshed my memory on ks-- the commands section isn't chrooted (which is where you'd use the `user` command).

Comment: @MarkWagner Right, it's in the main section. I just pulled the user statements out into a separate file and put the `%include` in their place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've placed a file you want to include on the same DVD or USB media from which you are trying to install RHEL.

The key here is that the installation media is *not* mounted at `/` when you boot into it. Rather, `/` is mounted from the read-only filesystem image `/LiveOS/squashfs.img` on the installation media.

The DVD/USB media itself gets mounted at `/run/install/repo` in RHEL 7. So if you placed a file `mystuff.ks` in the top level directory of the installation media, you will find it at `/run/install/repo/mystuff.ks`.

Comment: I'm installing from a local ISO file, like:

`/srv/distros/centos.iso`


All of the kickstart files are at:

`/srv/distros/ks`

Comment: @iletras OK, but how do you expect the installation to be able to read the kickstart files, then?

Comment: @Mark Hampton, it's been dawning on me that it's a false assumption :)
So the way to do it is to unpack the ISO and point to a location within it?

Comment: @iletras There are probably many things you could do, but it depends on how you're deploying these machines, whether they're physical or virtual, where the kickstart files are hosted, and maybe things I haven't thought of. Creating a custom ISO is certainly one possible option.